# How to use Spring's @Value without a properties file?

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

I currently have the following code:

```
int port = System.getProperty("port") != null ?
           Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port")) :
           8080;
```

I don't like this and would like to replace it with the Spring alternative. So, I thought I should use the `@Value` annotation. I don't want to have a properties file for this. However, I would like to have a default value via the annotation.

Is there a way to do this without a properties file and what would the proper code implementation be? Do I still need to have a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`? Could you please show me a working example of how to do this?

Comment: Can you please specify for which version of the spring answer is required?

Comment: 4.2.3.RELEASE, I  believe.... the last one before the latest one.

Comment: Just add `@PropertySourcesPalceholderConfigurer`, add `@Value("${port:8080}"`. Restart and be done. You don't need a properties file to use property sources. If you don't use the `@PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` you still can use SpEL but that would limit you only to system or environment properties and would become complex if you want to have a fallback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using java based configured.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Then annotate a field with `@Value`

```
@Value("${port:8080}")
private int port;
```

This will check the System properties and environment for the given property `port`. When having JNDI enabled that will be checked to and when having a servlet based environment you can have it as a servlet variable as well.

The use of the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't require property files it requires `PropertySource`s for which there are several different implementations.

If you don't want to register the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` you can revert to SpEL but that would make it a bit more complex (and ugly imho).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried, but you could use any [SpEL expression](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html). Your code could be rewritten as:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['port'] ?: 8080}")
private int port;
```

Note that I'm using the [safe navigation operator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-operator-safe-navigation).

Regarding `PropertySourcesPalceholderConfigurer`, I don't think you need one, given you have the Spring Expression Language dependency in your classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working.

1. Yes, you need `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` however it does not require property file
2. Reference your system variable like this: `@Value("#{systemEnvironment['YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME'] ?: 'DEFAULT_VALUE'}"`

Code sample:

```
package abc;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Test {

    public final String javaPath;

    @Autowired
    public Test(@Value("#{systemEnvironment['Path']}") String javaPath) {
        this.javaPath = javaPath;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("abc")
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Running all the sample:

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        Test bean = context.getBean(Test.class);
        System.out.println(bean.javaPath);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.